# Get all the content from an element using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have the following HTML strucuture from which I am trying to extract the first h2 and the first paragraph:

```
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse facilisis nisl nec varius venenatis.</h2>
<p>Praesent at ante vel metus condimentum pharetra quis bibendum risus. Nam semper et massa eu fermentum. <a href="#"> Sed vehicula leo </a> vel quam dignissim consectetur.</p>
<p> Nam semper et massa eu fermentum. </p>
<p> .....
```

This is the code I have that uses DOMDocument which works for the heading in the HTML above but it doesn't work for the paragraph - gets only the text upto the link which I suppose makes sense as it is probably created as another node. How would I change the function below so that it will get all of the first paragraph text?

```
function getSnippet ($html) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $headings = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h2');
    $paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

    $snippet = '';

    $firsth2 = $headings->item(0);
    $snippet .= $firsth2->firstChild->nodeValue;

    $firstp = $paragraphs->item(0);
    $snippet .= $firstp->firstChild->nodeValue;

    return $snippet;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the text content of the node:

```
$snippet .= $firstp->textContent;
```

PHP Docs: [php.net DOMNode->textContent](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [textContent](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_textcontent.asp):

```
$snippet .= $firstp->firstChild.textContent;
```

Comment: You are grabbing `$firstp->firstChild` and concatenating an undefined constant `textContent`